# How to make JWPlayer keep playing after a page redirect action

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, playback

I have a JWPlayer playing video in a page, when people accidentally click a link in that page or the F5 button, the player will stop playing automatically and start to redirect to other page. 
I use below function to help viewer to make sure this action is not made accidentally, but this could not keep the player continue playing, so is there any solution?

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){...};
```

Comment: onbeforeunload will just fire to alert user that you are redirecting but not stop the page to redirect

Comment: Below code can stop the redirect, but could not stop the player stopping.$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
  return 'are you sure blablabla';
 });

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to update a cookie with the player's position on reload, then do seek on('ready') with that value. I don't think you can continue video play when a page is reloaded, but this would give the impression of continuous play.

Comment: People may not happy with the cut of playing, that's why I want to find a way to fix this